# Hibernate- manytomany get all elements

Tags: hibernate

When I try  get All the Groups, I'm getting a duplicate records of the group if it has many to many relation

Group Entity:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinTable(name = "sp_yardgroup", schema = "store_documents", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "yard"))
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private List<Store> yards =  new ArrayList<Store>()
```

GroupYardEntity:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "sp_yardgroup", schema = "store_documents",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "yard", insertable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
public Set<CustomGroup> getGroups() {
    return groups;
}
```

If I switch to Lazy fetchType, I'll get lazyException when I try to call getById method in edit page, but it will display the correct list

Dao

```
@Transactional
public List<CustomGroup> getGroups() {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(CustomGroup.class);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: may be dont mention @JoinTable annotation in both entities.keep it only in one entity and try

Comment: well, doesn't need @JoinTable annotation in both entities, but I still have the duplicate records

Comment: Thanks for helping me @rakesh

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, needed to add the " @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)"

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinTable(name = "sp_yardgroup", schema = "store_documents", 
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"), 
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "yard"))
 @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Store> yards =  new ArrayList<Store>();
```